# can i install kubernetes on amazon linux 2

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, centos7, kubectl, cri-o

I'm having trouble Installing kubeadm on my amazon linux 2 instance specifically when i try to create a cluster,
when i try Installing runtime i get to chose which one to use :
containerd
CRI-O
Docker Engine
Mirantis Container Runtime
first of all i'm wondering which one i should use between them that is compatible with amazon linux 2 and second of all whenever i run yum install for any CRI i get this same error:
[image]

this is the output of the command: yum install cri-o

the doc that i followed is: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi, hope you are enjoying your kubernetes Journey !

First off, you I wanna tell you that you can use whichever you want between the container runtime you want to install.

You can use docker if you are not familiar with the others but containerd is in my opinion the best lightweight alternative ( containerd is used in docker, but for kubernetes you don't need all the layers that docker provides only the container runtime Itself, here containerd ) you can read this for more info, but there is plenty of documentation about this.: https://www.tutorialworks.com/difference-docker-containerd-runc-crio-oci/

Second of all, I don't know how you are trying to install your kubernetes cluster but again there is few couples of way to do it:

The hardest but very instructive can be kubernetes the hard way ( https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way )
Next you can use kubeadm (again there is plenty of documentation on the internet but you can follow one of the kubeadm tutorials: https://devopscube.com/setup-kubernetes-cluster-kubeadm/ )

Here is a list of tools that you can use to install your kubernetes cluster, you can look for tutorials for each of them on the internet: https://dzone.com/articles/50-useful-kubernetes-tools )

Last but not least, since you are on aws, you can use the AWS EKS service to setup quickly a robust kubernetes cluster. (https://aws.amazon.com/fr/eks/)

This is for AWS. If you want a local k8s cluster I strongly suggest you to use kind (kubernetes in docker)

Bguess

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation and quick response,
my biggest issue is that same error code that is in the screenshot everytime i try to install any CRI i get that same error (when i run any yum command) i think it's related to  /etc/yum.repos.d/